# How do i change the base url of my application from : http://test.something.com/ to http://test.something.com/abc.cfm

Tags: coldfusion, cgi

The url : **http://test.something.com/** is the login page of the application. By default it calls a page 'login.cfm'. But it doesnt shows in the url. May be it is defined in the server file as a default page.
What I want is, when i access this url [http://test.something.com/], the url should also show the called page i.e. the url should look like : **http://test.something.com/login.cfm** everytime.

I dumped the cgi variables and below is the stack for the same. I was wondering whether i have to change the cgi.http_referer or cgi.http_host.
Or do I need to change some file on the server side? I am using Apache.

EDITED:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(You forgot to show the cgi scope dump, fyi)

Are you certain that Application.cfc/Application.cfm isn't just showinng the login page? Also look in any header files. That's the likely scenario always showing the login page.

Anyway, you can use .htaccess to do just this but it's not clear whether you want each subdirectory to its index.cfm, or if you want to redirect to the root.

If you want the redirect to the index page of the current directory (/something/ redirects to /something/index.cfm)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^((.*)$) /$1/index.cfm [L,R=301]
```

If, instead, you want it to redirect to the root folder, that's a pretty simple change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^((.*)$) /index.cfm [L,R=301]
```

The `L` in both examples stops processing of rules after that, so if you have other rules in .htaccess, that may be a concern.

The `R` flag (`R=301`) is important to cause the URL to visibly change, creating the effect you want.

Comment: Yes, Application page only has session management code and variable initialization. Later it calls index.cfm which has an include of login page. So basically you call index.cfm or login.cfm, it will show you the login page. Can u please elaborate how will i use your solution in my code?

Comment: It is already redirecting to the index.cfm. My requirement is I want to show this file in the url. I mean if i hit http://test.something.com/ it will call index file but does not show up in the url. I want to alter that and make the url like : http://test.something.com/index.cfm

Comment: @vasu These are `.htaccess` file examples. Place a file called `".htaccess"` (without the quotes) in your root folder with the contents as I've shown above, and that should append index.cfm to your directory in all cases where the path doesn't contain a period (keeping it simple) so basically, it covers cases where there's no extension in the path (like page2.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking might be a browser dependent issue. In the Browser there is option to trim the URL from the address bar, which might be the case for you.
Please check this link and get it confirmed.

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-show-the-full-url-in-firefox/

Still if you want to change your application's URL to look something else then you can try "URL rewrite"
You can check this link for URL rewrite.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template